# Google Chat API: Delete message from bot gives a 401 error

Tags: google-apps-script, hangouts-api

This is the code i'm trying to use for deleting messages posted through a webhook to a chat room (I grab messageID when I create It with this same request but POST method and sending message in a text variable):

```
var WEBHOOK_URL2 = "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/<SPACE>/messages/<MESSAGEID>.<MESSAGEID>?key=<KEY>&token=<TOKEN>%3D";
  var options = {
    'method' : 'delete',
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(WEBHOOK_URL2, options);
  Logger.log (response);
```

The response is

```
"error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
```

As commented, creating messages works with those credentials (key / token from chatroom webhook) Maybe i am missing something from the documentation at https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/delete ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

That error usually occurs because the request lacks the access token or that access token wasn't validated. I assume that you are using Apps Script for this task. If my assumption is true, you'll find this [reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#clientside) useful; it summarizes the OAuth 2.0 protocol for Google APIs using JavaScript. For obtaining access tokens, please refer to this other [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#obtainingaccesstokens) for a complete step-by-step. Please, follow those steps on your request routine and don't hesitate to write back if you need more help.